# How set @ForeignKey jdo tables java

Tags: java, jdo

I have two tables named: t1, t2, t3.

```
      t1 consists of the following columns: id(PK), name
      t2 consists of the following columns: idPr(PK), id(FK), client
      t3 consists of the following columns: idF(PK), id(FK), idPr(FK), date
```

and these are the classes that I made:

```
 @PersistenceCapable 
 public class t1{

  @Persistent
  @PrimaryKey
  private String id;

  @Persistent
  private String name;

  ...

 }

 @PersistenceCapable 
 public class t2{


  @Persistent
  @PrimaryKey
  private String idPr;

  @Persistent
  private String id;


  @Persistent
  private String client;

       .......
 }


 @PersistenceCapable 
 public class t3{


  @Persistent
  @PrimaryKey
  private String idF;

  @Persistent
  private String id;

  @Persistent
  private String idPr;

  @Persistent
  private String date;

     ............
 }
```

How do I set the records about the foreign keys?
I had a look [here](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/annotations.html#ForeignKey_Class) but I did not understand how to set them among the different classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fail to see how you can have any "foreign keys" in that example since you have no relationships between classes. When you put in some relationships then foreign keys are created for you and the @ForeignKey is only to define the FK "name" and precise constraint details

Comment: I tried to add @ForeignKey(name="name_") before the foreign key but in the database does not create foreign keys!

Comment: I already said, YOU HAVE NO RELATIONSHIPS, so NO Foreign keys will be created. Add some relationships to your classes then there is basis for a question

Comment: could you give me an example of one of the relationships to be added to the classes? thank you!

Comment: What are the relationships between T1, T2 and T3 classes ? 1-1, 1-N, M-N? Nobody can give an example unless you tell us what you're trying to achieve. 1-1 relations for example are defined in http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_3/jdo/orm/one_to_one.html

Comment: For example, I created two classes in this way: [link](http://pastebin.com/Mf55Xr7f)  In the class "B" when I add new data how do I add a "isbn" of class "A"?

Comment: In that "example" the field in B of type "A" should be called "a" since it is an Object A. If you want to access the "isbn" of that object you get your B object and called getA().getIsbn(). This is nothing to do with JDO, and is simple Java object relationships

Comment: Ok, but the constructor of the class "B" as I create it? I have to pass it as a parameter to the instance of the class "A"?

Comment: Create your objects and fields of objects as you feel like, constructor or setter. As already said, this is basic Java, nothing to do with JDO, or ForeignKeys (what this question is about)